# Retrieval of user's likes using Facebook Graph API sometimes fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

in our game I'm checking if user is liking some of our Facebook sites.
For most users its working but there are some complaining that they are
having problems with this functionality.

1) I'm requesting "user_likes" permission during logging to Facebook
   ( users must be logged ).

2) I also take into account so called "paging" of result via Graph API.
( I'm retrieving all user's like-ids piecewise and after many tests
I assumed that it's working fine :o) )

3) Those users that were reporting that this check isn't working
   really "like" those sites (before running this check).

So my assumption is that request "me/likes" fails or doesn't work
as expected under some conditions. Can someone help me with this
problem?

It seems that I'm not alone because I found these (unluckily unanswered):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772814/checking-facebook-graph-api-for-user-likes-fails-for-some-users
- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10109773/cant-obtain-user-likes-in-some-cases-using-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only cause I can think of is the Graph cache not being up to date with the user's Like data. If the user only just liked a page, and then you requested the Like data via Graph API, the data may not have been updated yet and therefore would show up as a "non-Liked" page.

Try using a FQL query to do the same check - but instead of paging through the user's like, do a direct check on the Page ID, User ID and Like status. You will have to join across multiple tables to get it working.

Comment: Shouldn't be this "SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=[PageID]" sufficient?